# How to add Imagick or Gmagick Library to CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I am a newbie in CodeIgniter. And would like to know how am I suppose to add Imagick/Gmagick ilbrary to codeigniter, so that I can use it in my codes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) explains it nicely (EDIT: [another article on it](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/libraries.html)).

According to the guide, you can place the library you want included under application/libraries. Whenever you want to load this library in a controller, you use

```
$this->load->library('class name');
```